# Xamarin Forms Svg Gradient background

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms

So im trying to implement a svg gradiant background image but when i set the svg image it only displays the solid colour(gradient just doesnt display).

This is the code im using and ive tested it on regular svg images and works fine but doesnt work whenever I add a gradient svg file.

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new ContentPage
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children =
            {
                new SvgImage
                {
                    SvgPath = "SVG_Test.Images.drawing.svg",
                    SvgAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                    HeightRequest = 1000,
                    WidthRequest = 500
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?